# Running java on each line in a file as input

Tags: java, bash, shell

I am new to bash Scripting.
I want to run a java program using script on each line of a file

I am writing this script, but I don't know what's the correct script. I however am able to extract all the lines individually. Following is the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'   # make newlines the only separator
set -f          # disable globbing
for i in $(cat "$1"); do
        java Interpreter $i >output.txt   
done
```

I want the output to be in a file or atleast on the screen.
Interpreter is the name of my program.

**EDIT**

My program reads from standard console and writes to it.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Java isn't compiled line by line.

Comment: I am trying to compile on every line. Each line as a different instance of java program.

Comment: Until Java 9 comes out with a proper interpreted Java system, this is **not possible** to accomplish without ***a lot*** of overhead/boilerplate.  It's unclear to me what you're really wanting to accomplish by doing this.

Comment: @Makoto Inatead of running program 300 times manually. I am trying to run the program 300 times based on the input from text file.

Comment: This makes no sense.  Why would you want to do that at all?

Comment: Because I am testing my program on 300 different input.

Comment: Setting aside the fact that using `> output.txt` will overwrite all but the last run, perhaps you just want `xargs`?

Comment: Yes, that would overwrite, but I can easily find out how to append instead of overwrite. But the problem is to compile run it 300 times with different input each time.

Comment: Follow a naming scheme (e.g. `file1`, `file2`, or read from args `input`, `input1`, `input2`, etc) and loop? If this was a quick tool I would probably just hard code the values and run it.

Comment: You really need to understand the difference between compiling and running. You want to run your program on 300 different outputs, not compile it. Compiling is the process of using javac to transform .java files into .class files.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But in my question I mention that I want to run a java program using script...

Comment: You want `xargs`.

Comment: @Makoto as you can see, I am trying to run the complete program on each line, "java Interpreter ... " . I do not think that my answer is having **a lot** of over head, and is really possible.

Comment: @Rogue thanks, that was some constructive comment, unlike many others.

Comment: @chrylis I have mentioned one of the answers, I am new to bash scripting as you can see from my question. I do not know how to use xargs. If you have an answer, I would really love to learn how to use xargs in this case.

Comment: I *couldn't* see it, which is why I asked the clarifying questions I did.  I now understand that you want to have 300 different inputs, which is a different question structure than the one you're posing.  How you handle these inputs depends on how your program is structured, which we'd need to see to give you a *better* answer.  Just showing us the bash script doesn't help us since we don't know how your Java application would accept these arguments.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for asking, I as a person who asked a question can clarify. But who ever marks it down, I do not think this is an irrelevant question.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'   # make newlines the only separator
set -f          # disable globbing
for i in $(cat "$1"); do
        echo $i > bhavya
        java Interpreter < bhavya >> output4567.txt
done
```